# When are constants garbage collected in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

1. When does the `Class` object assigned to a constant get garbage collected? E.g.

   ```
   class Foo; end
   Bar = Class.new {}
   ```
2. When does a constant declared inside an anonymous class/module get garbage collected? E.g.

   ```
   foo = Class.new do
     self::NAME = "Bar"
   end
   foo::NAME  # Bar
   foo = nil 
   GC.start
   ```

   In the example above, will the constant `NAME` declared inside the anonymous class be garbage collected? ( I am assuming the anonymous class will be garbage collected..)

Comment: By “when”, do you really want to know “when can“? Answering the first is dependent on many other variables, the second isn’t.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall In scenario 1, I want know if it will ever be garbage collected. In scenario 2 I want to know if the `NAME` constant is garbage collected when garbage collection request is submitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s easy to boil this down to the very general case: *if an object no longer has any references to it, it can be garbage collected*. Note that I say *object*, not *variable*. Variables are not garbage collected, objects are.

---

Now let’s look at your given examples:

```
class Foo; end
Bar = Class.new {}
```

Instances of `Class` will only be garbage collected if the constant they’re assigned to (if any) is reassigned to a different value (e.g. `Bar = nil`) and there are no instances of that class and there are no Classes which inherit from it.

```
foo = Class.new do
  self::NAME = "Bar"
end
foo::NAME  # Bar
foo = nil
```

The values previously in `foo` & `foo::NAME` can be garbage collected if there were no other references to them (i.e. this snippet is the complete code).